# Java compare the data from method to hashmap in another method

Tags: java, io, bufferedreader

This code is reading the textfile and creating HashMap. What I want to do is to compare the StatusMAP method in my ModelOne.txt and ModelTwo.txt

Let's say my ModelOne.txt has data like this:

> Model1, 54321, Test, Online

And on my ModelTwo.txt has data like this:

> Model2, 12345, Check, OFF

I already know how to get the indexes data in textfile, but what I can't do is to compare those two data from two on each other with base on StatusMAP. So basically if the ModelOne.txt compare to ModelTwo.txt it will get the index[3] then it will compare if the index[3] is Online in ModelOne it should be OL in ModelTwo if it's not, it will going to print 'Not equal' otherwise 'They're Equal'.

This is really quite long to read, but any help, suggestions or comments would be appreciated. Thanks in advance guys.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.io.*;

    public class ReadTxt {

      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        ReadTxt obj = new ReadTxt();
        obj.PackageMAP();
        obj.StatusMAP();
        obj.ReadModelOne();
        obj.ReadModelTwo();

      }

      public static void StatusMAP() {
          Map<String, String> hashstatus = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
          hashstatus.put("Offline", "OFF");
          hashstatus.put("Online", "OL");
       }


      public static void PackageMAP() {

        String csvFile = "Names.txt";
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line = "";
        String cvsSplitBy = ",";

        try {

            Map<String, String> maps = new HashMap<String, String>();

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                // use comma as separator
                String[] packagecode = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

                maps.put(packagecode[0], packagecode[1]);

            }

            //loop map
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : maps.entrySet()) {

                System.out.println("Name Package one \t" + entry.getKey()
                + "\t"
                + "|"
                + "\t"
                + "Name Package two \t"
                + entry.getValue());


            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("This is all the Name packages");
      }


       public static void ReadModelOne() throws Exception{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("ModelOne.txt"));
        String line = null;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
          String[] MOne_STATUS = line.split(",");
          for (String inputOne : MOne_STATUS) {
          inputOne = MOne_STATUS[2];

          }
        }
        br.close(); 
      }

      public static void ReadModelTwo() throws Exception{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("ModelTwo.txt"));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] MTwo_STATUS = line.split(",");
            for (String inputTwo : MTwo_STATUS) {
                inputTwo = MTwo_STATUS[2];

            }   
        }
        br.close(); 
    }


        public static void checkStatus() {

        // do the checking here for status

    }


    }
```

Comment: What is method `StatusMAP` for? It creates a local variable and returns nothing. How, you think, can ``hashstatus` be used from other methods?

Comment: Uhhmmm... Why are you creating a `ReadTxt` if you're only using static methods?

Comment: @skozlov  - let's say the StatusMAP hash is like the hash on PackageMAP. I just didn't update the code sorry, but lets say the variable holding for StatusMAP is the packagecode. it returns the value of hashmap

Comment: @fabian what is the best method for Readtxt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as follows,

```
String data1 = "Model1, 54321, Test, Online";
String data2 = "Model2, 12345, Check, OFF";

String output = (data1.split(", ")[3].equalsIgnoreCase("Online") && 
                 data2.split(", ")[3].equalsIgnoreCase("OL")) ? 
                 "Equal" :
                 "Not Equal";

System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: I can't use this one, I'm reading a text file with thousand of lines. That's why I put it on foreach loop.

Comment: @tuturyokgaming I just paste how to compare the two separate datas taken from two different files. You can just take the comparision logic only.